# Windows Phone sdk 7 and .net framework compatibility issue?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone, .net-framework-version

I want to write a Windows phone app, I am running Windows 7 64 bit and I have Visual Studio 2015. When I try to install Windows phone SDK 7, I get an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwxGv.png).

How can I fix this? Is it an incompatibility problem?

Comment: Well, the error message pretty clearly states that these two products (.NET Framework and the other) are **incompatible** and must be uninstalled before you can install the WinPhone7 SDK - did you install these two products mentioned?